# Move array with days of week one day backwards js

Tags: javascript

I have such code

```
const weekDays = [
    { label: 'Mon', name: 'Monday' },
    { label: 'Tue', name: 'Tuesday' },
    { label: 'Wed', name: 'Wednesday' },
    { label: 'Thu', name: 'Thursday' },
    { label: 'Fri', name: 'Friday' },
    { label: 'Sat', name: 'Saturday' },
    { label: 'Sun', name: 'Sunday' },
];
 let daysOfWeek = ['Tue','Thu', 'Sun']

const firstDayIndex = weekDays.findIndex(day => day.label === daysOfWeek[0]) // get current day index
daysOfWeek.unshift(weekDays[(firstDayIndex || weekDays.length) - 1].label) // add previous day by index
daysOfWeek.pop() // remove last day
console.log(daysOfWeek)
```

Now daysOfWeek shows `["Mon", "Tue", "Thu"]` but I wanted daysOfWeek to show `["Mon", "Wed", "Sat"]` I mean, for each item of daysOfWeek to be one day backwards

Comment: @pilchard all I want is to move each element of daysOfWeek array backwards by one day dynamically whatever the length of daysOfWeek, for example, convert ['Mon','Thu', 'Sun'] to ['Sun','Wed', 'Sat'] or convert ['Sun','Mon', 'Fri'] to ['Mon','Sun', 'Sat'] so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a circular doubly linked list, here indexed in an object by `label`.

```js
const weekDays = [{ label: 'Mon', name: 'Monday' }, { label: 'Tue', name: 'Tuesday' }, { label: 'Wed', name: 'Wednesday' }, { label: 'Thu', name: 'Thursday' }, { label: 'Fri', name: 'Friday' },{ label: 'Sat', name: 'Saturday' },{ label: 'Sun', name: 'Sunday' }];

const days_list = weekDays
  .map((day) => ({ day, prev: null, next: null }))
  .reduce((list, node, idx, arr) => {
    node.next = arr[(idx + 1) % arr.length];
    node.prev = arr[(idx + arr.length - 1) % arr.length];

    list[node.day.label] = node;

    return list;
  }, {});

const daysOfWeek = ['Tue', 'Thu', 'Sun'];

const prevDays = daysOfWeek.map((label) => days_list[label].prev.day.label);
console.log(...prevDays); // Mon Wed Sat

const nextDays = daysOfWeek.map((label) => days_list[label].next.day.label);
console.log(...nextDays); // Wed Fri Mon

// update daysOfWeek
daysOfWeek.forEach((label, i) => (daysOfWeek[i] = days_list[label].prev.day.label));

console.log('updated daysOfWeek: ', ...daysOfWeek);
```

As noted in the comments, using an extra two loops to make the list is not particularly efficient, even if the result is convenient to use. An alternative would be to declare utility functions to get the next/prev day given a label.

```
function next_day(label) {
  let index = weekDays.findIndex((day) => day.label === label);
  if (index === -1) throw `'${label}' is not a valid day label`;
  index = index === weekDays.length - 1 ? 0 : index;

  return weekDays[index + 1];
}

function prev_day(label) {
  let index = weekDays.findIndex((day) => day.label === label);
  if (index === -1) throw `'${label}' is not a valid day label`;
  index = index === 0 ? weekDays.length : index;

  return weekDays[index - 1];
}
```

```js
const weekDays = [{ label: 'Mon', name: 'Monday' }, { label: 'Tue', name: 'Tuesday' }, { label: 'Wed', name: 'Wednesday' }, { label: 'Thu', name: 'Thursday' }, { label: 'Fri', name: 'Friday' },{ label: 'Sat', name: 'Saturday' },{ label: 'Sun', name: 'Sunday' }];

function next_day(label) {
  let index = weekDays.findIndex((day) => day.label === label);
  if (index === -1) throw `'${label}' is not a valid day label`;
  index = index === weekDays.length - 1 ? 0 : index;

  return weekDays[index + 1];
}

function prev_day(label) {
  let index = weekDays.findIndex((day) => day.label === label);
  if (index === -1) throw `'${label}' is not a valid day label`;
  index = index === 0 ? weekDays.length : index;

  return weekDays[index - 1];
}

const daysOfWeek = ['Tue', 'Thu', 'Sun'];

const prevDays = daysOfWeek.map((day) => prev_day(day).label);
console.log('prevDays: ', ...prevDays); // Mon Wed Sat

const nextDays = daysOfWeek.map((day) => next_day(day).label);
console.log('nextDays: ', ...nextDays); // Wed Fri Mon

// or change daysOfWeek in place
daysOfWeek.forEach((day, i) => (daysOfWeek[i] = prev_day(day).label));
console.log('updated daysOfWeek: ', ...daysOfWeek);
```

These two functions share a lot of logic and can easily be combined into a single `offset_day` utility function which accepts an `offset` to return days *+n* or *-n* from the passed day label, if offset is omitted, 0, or evenly divisible by `weekDays.length`, it returns the day object of the passed label.

```
function offset_day(label, offset = 0) {
  let index = weekDays.findIndex((day) => day.label === label);

  if (index === -1) throw `'${label}' is not a valid day label`;

  const length = weekDays.length;
  const _offset = offset % length;
  if (_offset) {
    index = index + _offset;
    index = index < 0 ? index + length : index >= length ? index - length : index;
  }

  return weekDays[index];
}
```

```js
const weekDays = [{ label: 'Mon', name: 'Monday' }, { label: 'Tue', name: 'Tuesday' }, { label: 'Wed', name: 'Wednesday' }, { label: 'Thu', name: 'Thursday' }, { label: 'Fri', name: 'Friday' },{ label: 'Sat', name: 'Saturday' },{ label: 'Sun', name: 'Sunday' }];

function offset_day(label, offset = 0) {
  let index = weekDays.findIndex((day) => day.label === label);

  if (index === -1) throw `'${label}' is not a valid day label`;

  const length = weekDays.length;
  const _offset = offset % length;
  if (_offset) {
    index = index + _offset;
    index = index < 0 ? index + length : index >= length ? index - length : index;
  }

  return weekDays[index];
}

const daysOfWeek = ['Tue', 'Thu', 'Sun'];

const prevDays = daysOfWeek.map((day) => offset_day(day, -1).label);
console.log('prevDays: ', ...prevDays); // Mon Wed Sat

const nextDays = daysOfWeek.map((day) => offset_day(day, 1).label);
console.log('nextDays: ', ...nextDays); // Wed Fri Mon

// offset by 'n' days either way
const minusThree = daysOfWeek.map((day) => offset_day(day, -3).label);
console.log('minusThree: ', ...minusThree); // Sat Mon Thur

const plusThree = daysOfWeek.map((day) => offset_day(day, 3).label);
console.log('plusThree: ', ...plusThree); // Fri Sun Wed
```

Comment: Is it actually necessary to have 2 `map` and one `reduce` to achieve one itration? Also this is generating new variables `prevDays` and `nextDays` rather than updating the original variable `daysOfWeek` which as the actual requirement mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through `daysOfWeek` and find its occurance index in `weekDays`. Update the node from `daysOfWeek` with the index reference from `weekDays`

**Previous day Working Fiddle**

```js
const weekDays = [{ label: 'Mon', name: 'Monday' }, { label: 'Tue', name: 'Tuesday' }, { label: 'Wed', name: 'Wednesday' }, { label: 'Thu', name: 'Thursday' }, { label: 'Fri', name: 'Friday' },{ label: 'Sat', name: 'Saturday' },{ label: 'Sun', name: 'Sunday' }];
const daysOfWeek = ['Tue', 'Thu', 'Sun'];
// const daysOfWeek = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Sun'];
daysOfWeek.forEach((day, dayIndex) => {
    let index = weekDays.findIndex(item => item.label === day);
    index = index === 0 ? weekDays.length : index;
    index !== -1 ? daysOfWeek[dayIndex] = weekDays[index - 1].label : null;
});
console.log(daysOfWeek);
```

**Next day working logic**

```js
const weekDays = [{ label: 'Mon', name: 'Monday' },{ label: 'Tue', name: 'Tuesday' },{ label: 'Wed', name: 'Wednesday' },{ label: 'Thu', name: 'Thursday' },{ label: 'Fri', name: 'Friday' },{ label: 'Sat', name: 'Saturday' },{ label: 'Sun', name: 'Sunday' }];
let daysOfWeek = ['Tue', 'Thu', 'Sun'];
// let daysOfWeek = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Sat'];
daysOfWeek.forEach((day, dayIndex) => {
    let index = weekDays.findIndex(item => item.label === day);
    // index = index === 0 ? weekDays.length : index;
    if (index !== -1) {
        index = index === weekDays.length - 1 ? -1 : index;
        daysOfWeek[dayIndex] = weekDays[index + 1].label;
    }
});
console.log(daysOfWeek);
```

Comment: hey)) if I use ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Sun'] I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'label'

Comment: exactly, whatever the size even if seven days then each day is moved backwards by one

Comment: sorry just last comment)), if I change weekDays[index - 1].label to weekDays[index + 1].label. Will the calculation be vice versa like forwards?)))